# Dlib face detection small object size

Tags: image-processing, dlib

I have been evaluating the performance of dlib for a while. Today I have realized that the standard face detector (ie. created with dlib::get_frontal_face_detector() method) finds faces that are 73x73. However I know that, dlib can find at least 80x80 objects if there is no upsampling. as far as I know there is no upsampling in standard face detector.

I know that dlib::frontal_face_detector is a typedef:

```
typedef object_detector<scan_fhog_pyramid<pyramid_down<6> > > frontal_face_detector;
```

So by reading this typedef, one can conclude that this detector always downscaling the image by the ratio: 5/6 = 0,83.

So what is the explanation of this situation?
Sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about the time of upsampling some image.

If you check out the dlib-example `fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp` you will see, that it's by default upsampling the image by a factor of 2. This is sometimes a good idea based on the task. If you objects to detect are *far away* and your image-input is small (e.g. VGA-res) you should do something like that (as you won't have much fun detecting 10x10 objects).

The example you are mentioning is something else, which is elemental to these kind of object-detectors. The 5/6-ratio defines the downsample-ratio for the [image-pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)). These are multi-scale representations about some given image.

Why do we need this (as it results in much more work):

- We want to detect objects at varying scales (not all faces are 73x73; we also want detect a face if it's 85x85)

When combined with a sliding-window, we are somewhat robust to varying scales and location of objects.